# How to fetch data from mongodb using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm try to fetch data from mongoDB using this code in node.js, but It's not working even not show any error or result. I have already test DB, there is lots for data available like [Database output]

```
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("597321311e13c57335727a6d"),
    "name" : "Amanda",
    "publisher" : "MTV india"
    }
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5973220b1e13c57335727a6e"),
    "name" : "Deepka",
    "publisher" : "MTV"
    }
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("597322141e13c57335727a6f"),
    "name" : "sunil",
    "publisher" : "MTV india"
    }
```

1. app.js

   ```
   var express = require('express');
   var app = express();
   var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
   var mongoose = require('mongoose');
   var booksDetail = require('./modal/book');
   var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/example";

   // Connect to the db
   MongoClient.connect(url);


   app.get('/api/books', function(req,res) {
       res.send("on book  page");
       booksDetail.find({})
       .exec(function(err, books) {
           console.log("--working--");
         if(err) {
           res.send('error occured')
           res.send('error occured')
         } else {
           console.log(books);
           res.json(books);
         }
       });

   });

   app.get('/api/school', function(req,res){
       res.send('hello this is school page');
   });

   app.listen(7900);
   console.log('server is runing 7900')
   ```
2. modal/book.js

   ```
   var mongoose = require('mongoose');
   var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

   var bookSchema = new Schema({
           name: {
               type: String,
               requierd: true
           },
           publisher : {
               type: String,
               requierd: true
           }   
   })

   module.exports = mongoose.model('booksDetail', bookSchema);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't connected to your MongoDB server (using mongoose) yet.

Choose to use either mongoose or mongodb library, not both. Check it docs carefully.

Answer (score 0):

you load mongo and mongoose but you connect using mongo and your document is stored with mongoose. So just remove mongo and connect with mongoose

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/example');
var db = mongoose.connection;  
db.once('open', function() {
    console.log('OPEN');
});
```

Comment: thanks sheplu,  I have update your code not its says :
<!-------------------------- >

(node:9628) DeprecationWarning: `open()` is deprecated in mongoose >= 4.11.0, us
e `openUri()` instead, or set the `useMongoClient` option if using `connect()` o
r `createConnection()`. See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#use-mong
o-client

<!-------------------------- >

(node:9628) DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default promise l
ibrary) is deprecated, plug in your own promise library instead: http://mongoose
js.com/docs/promises.html